# Implement fingerprint in mobile banking android app

Tags: android, authentication, fingerprint, biometrics

I am developing one android app for banking transaction. I want to implement the finger print login feature but I don't want to use the device registered fingerprint. I want the user to register the fingerprint through my app . How can I implement,save and validate the data.Please answer.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Fingerprint_Authentication_Tutorial

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in the above mentioned tutorial also they are using  the device registered finger print only. But I specifically want to register the fingerprint through the app.

Comment: As Mr. Lake points out, there is nothing in Android for this. You are welcome to contact the device manufacturer for your desired device and see if they have any proprietary APIs that you can use for direct access to fingerprint scans. Or, you are welcome to contact the manufacturer of external fingerprint readers and learn about their Android integration APIs.

Answer (score 1):

On Android, applications do not have direct access to fingerprint data so you cannot register fingerprints within your app.

Comment: Thanks a lot.But I  want to know if there is any other way to implement it through app registration.

Comment: No, sorry. The Android CDD actually specifically disallows manufacturers from making fingerprint data available to apps.